# Precise relationship between classical and quantum Fourier transform for a finite abelian group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, fourier-analysis, representation-theory, quantum-computation

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle#1|}$
I asked this question on the quantum computing SE site a few weeks ago, but got no responses, so I thought I might try posting it here.

I am trying to figure out the precise relationship (if any) between the quantum Fourier transform for finite *abelian* groups and the classical Fourier transform for those groups. Here is my attempt so far…

Suppose $G$ is a finite abelian group. We know $G\cong\Z/n_1\Z\times\dots\times\Z/n_r\Z$ For some positive integers $n_1,\dots,n_r$, so I write the irreducible characters of $G$ as
$$
\chi_x(g) = \prod_{j=1}^r\exp(2\pi i x_j g_j/n_j)
$$
where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_r)\in G$ with each $x_i\in \Z/n_i\Z$, and likewise for $g\in G$.

The text I am using defines the Fourier transform of a function $f:G\to \C$ as the function $\widehat f:\widehat G \to \C$ such that
$$
\widehat f(\chi) = \langle f,\chi\rangle = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}f(g)\overline{\chi(g)}.
$$

Meanwhile I see the QFT for a finite abelian group defined as the linear transformation $F_G$ such that
$$
F_G\ket g = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|G|}}\sum_{x\in G}\chi_x(g)\ket x.
$$

Now, the classical Fourier transform is not applied to group elements but rather to maps $G\to\C$. It makes sense to think of a state like $\ket g$ (to which the QFT may be applied) as encoding the function on $G$ that is $1$ at $g$ and $0$ elsewhere. To draw a parallel between these two transforms, I thus considered applying the classical transform to the function $\delta_g:G\to \C$ that is $1$ at $g$ and $0$ elsewhere. As far as I can tell, then, the relationship between the classical and QFT for $G$ is
\begin{align*}
\bra x F_G\ket g &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{|G|}}\chi_x(g)\\ 
&= \sqrt{|G|}\overline{\left(\frac{1}{|G|}\overline{\chi_x(g)}\right)} \\
&= \sqrt{|G|} \left(\overline{\widehat\delta_g(\chi_x)}\right).
\end{align*}
So the equation I got above is very nearly what I'd expect: ignoring the normalization factor, it *almost* says that the $\ket x$th entry of $F_G\ket g$ is equal to $\widehat \delta_g(\chi_x)$, except there is a conjugate there.

The fact that we get this conjugate seemed a little odd to me, and I was wondering whether this is an indication that there is some error or inconsistency in my reasoning (or incompatibility between my definitions), or if it is just “the way things work.” Alternatively, is there any more direct way of relating the QFT to the ordinary Fourier transform for a finite abelian group?

Comment: The notation $|x\rangle$, while I believe to be somewhat common in physics, is relatively uncommon in "pure" Fourier analysis. Could you clarify the definition, possibly describing it in more familiar terms?

Comment: @AlexOrtiz They're just the names of basis vectors, like writing $|1\rangle$ instead of $e_1$ etc.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz To be more clear, I believe the convention here is to arbitrarily label group elements by standard basis vectors in $|G|$-dimensional complex space, and then write the standard basis vector associated with $g$ as $| g\rangle$. (Strictly speaking, I think the convention is actually use $d$-dimensional space, where $d$ is the smallest power of 2 greater than or equal to $|G|$, but I don't think it really matters too much here...)

Comment: There are different normalizations depending on what you want to be orthonormal (e.g. indicator functions vs. characters as functions $G\to\mathbb{C}$), so the $\sqrt{|G|}$ isn't mysterious: we often want the Fourier transform $f\mapsto\widehat{f}$ to be a unitary linear transformation between function spaces. It seems the QFT is calling that transformation $F_G$ (or the inverse transformation, technically, which is where the complex conjugate comes in). I'm sweeping under the rug, of course, the assumption of an identification $G\cong\widehat{G}$.

Comment: @runway44 Would you mind expanding on how the conjugate is coming from the inverse transform? Is it that $F_G$ is really encoding something more analogous to the classical inverse FT for $G$, because it maps a function like $\delta_g$ (or perhaps $\delta_{\chi_g}$) to $\chi_g$? I am confused because 1) I can't tell if it really does this in general, since as far as I can see this assumes $\chi_g(x) = \chi_x(g)$, which I thought is only true for some identifications of $G$ with $\widehat G$, and 2) if so, I can't quite see how this introduces a conjugate.

Comment: To be brief: these are simply different notations and conventions for the same thing. The complex conjugation _must_ enter somewhere, for example, but we do have choices about where to put it. The $\pi$'s can be moved around... Apparently the "discrete Dirac delta" at $g$ is sometimes identified with $g$ itself. Stuff like that. But the underlying transform-and-inversion (and Parseval-Plancherel theorem) is conceptually the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original motivation for Fourier analysis is decomposing functions into combinations of pure harmonics, waves, characters, irreps, or whatever you want to call the constituent pieces. So for a function $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ (where $G$ is abelian), we expect we can write $f$ as a linear combination $\sum \hat{f}(\chi)\chi$, where each character $\chi$ has a coefficient $\widehat{f}(\chi)$. In other words, $f(g)=\sum_{\chi\in\widehat{G}}\widehat{f}(\chi)\chi(g)$ for all $g\in G$, and we can think of the coefficients $\hat{f}$ as a function $\widehat{f}:\widehat{G}\to\mathbb{C}$.

At this point, let's say we choose an identification $G\cong\mathbb{Z}_{n_1}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}_{n_k}$ and use it to also create an identification with $\widehat{G}\cong\mathbb{Z}_{n_1}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}_{n_k}$ where we have the formula $\chi_x(g)=\exp(2\pi i \sum x_jg_j/n_j)$, as you've mentioned. This yields $\chi_x(g)=\chi_g(x)$ for any $x,g\in G$.

If we write $f$ as a linear combination of $\chi$s as in the aforementioned way, we have

$$ f(g)=\sum_{x\in G}\widehat{f}(x)\chi_x(g), \quad \widehat{f}(x)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}f(g)\overline{\chi_x(g)}. $$

However, if we use a different normalization to define the $\widehat{f}(\chi)$s, we can say

$$ f(g)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|G|}}\sum_{x\in G}\widehat{f}(x)\chi_x(g), \quad \widehat{f}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|G|}}\sum_{g\in G}f(g)\overline{\chi_x(g)}. $$

We will use this normalization. It's useful because then the act of taking the Fourier transform is a unitary transformation on the inner product space of functions $G\to\mathbb{C}$, and then as a linear operator it has order four. As you've defined it, we have a linear operator $F$ given by

$$ F=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|G|}}\sum_{x,g}\chi_x(g)|x\rangle\langle g|. $$

If we write a function as $|f\rangle=\sum_{g\in G}f(g)|g\rangle$, we may compute $F|\widehat{f}\rangle$ as

$$ \begin{array}{lll}
F|\widehat{f}\rangle & = & \displaystyle
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{|G|}}\left(\sum_{x,g,}\chi_x(g)|x\rangle\langle g|\right)\left(\sum_{h\in G}\widehat{f}(h)|h\rangle\right) \\
& = & \displaystyle
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{|G|}}\sum_{x,g}\chi_x(g)\widehat{f}(g)|x\rangle \\
& = & \displaystyle
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{|G|}}\sum_x\left(\sum_g\widehat{f}(g)\chi_g(x)\right)|x\rangle \\
& = & \displaystyle
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{|G|}}\sum_x f(x)|x\rangle \\
& = & \displaystyle = |f\rangle.
\end{array} $$

Interpret $F|\widehat{f}\rangle=|f\rangle$ as saying $F$ is the inverse Fourier transform. As the Wikipedia page for the QFT puts it: "the quantum Fourier transform has the same effect as the inverse discrete Fourier transform" (under this convention).